# Что за USB BICR функция в андроиде?

Tags: android

В файле `build.prop` я увидел следующее:

```
# USB BICR function
ro.sys.usb.bicr=yes
```

Я пробовал искать в интернете, но ничего дельного я там не нашёл, может быть вы подскажите чем управляет этот параметр?

Answer (score 0):

Для базы знаний скопирую ответ [отсюда](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/195414/what-is-usb-bicr-function-in-android):

> Я нашел некоторые подсказки в [исходниках ядра MediaTek (MTK)](https://github.com/andr3jx/MTK6577/blob/master/system/vold/Bicr.cpp).
>
> Нет описания, но, кажется, эта опция
>   позволяет вам представить виртуальный USB-CD-ROM при подключении через
>   USB к ПК. Часто это используется для предоставления определенных
>   драйверов, необходимых для доступа к специальным функциям устройства.
>   Виртуальный компакт-диск присутствует на устройстве Android в виде
>   ISO-образа.
>
> По моему мнению, этот параметр подходит только разработчикам,
>   создающим пользовательский ПЗУ.